# Linq Left outer Join with all columns select and bind to Gridview

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to bind grid view with Linq Left outer join (I want to select all columns from "prdct in context.Products").

My query is:

```
gridProducts.DataSource = (from prdct in context.Products
                           join comp in context.ProductCompanies on prdct.productCompany equals comp.prdctCompId 
                           into firstJoin
                           from fj in firstJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           join cat in context.ProductCategories on prdct.productCategory equals cat.prdctCatId
                           into finalresult
                           from fr in finalresult.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           select new
                                      {
                                          prd = prdct,
                                          fj.prdctCompName,
                                          fr.prdctCatName
                                      }).ToList();

gridProducts.DataBind();
```

I have checked the SQL generated by query it is showing records in SQL Server but it throws error in my application while binding to gridview:

> The data source for GridView with id 'grdD' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns. Ensure that your data source has content.

Comment: if you run just the Linq query - do you see any results?

Comment: Yes I am getting my desired result.